# shiny server actionButton and sliderInput

Tags: shiny

In shiny, I would like to have an actionButton setting a sliderInput to a prefined value.

The "natural way" would be to have something like

```
input$myslider <- eventReactive(input$mybutton,{
  15432
})
```

in the shinyServer function.
This does not work, and it also does not work when I use  `<<-` instead of `<-`

Is there a way of accomplishing what I want?

Comment: See `?updateSliderInput`,...

Answer (score 0):

changing `server.R` by adding

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

    observeEvent(input$reset,
               {
                 updateSliderInput(session,"votesshifted",value=15432)
               })
```

and adding an `actionButton("reset","Reset")` in ui.R
solved my problem.